# Como validar campos vacíos en angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formularios, validación

Soy nueva en angular e hice un formulario sencillo, como se validan los campos que no estén vacíos? o que sea solo números o solo letras?

Tengo el siguiente código en mi html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" style="background-color: rgba(28, 83, 236, 0.822);">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img class="brand" src="/assets/ejemplo.png">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: floralwhite;">Consulta Datos</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="formularioRegistro">
  <h2>Iniciar Sesión</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm!" (ngSubmit)="guardar">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Usuario:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="usuario" class="form-control" required>
      <label>Contraseña:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="contraseña" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right"> Acceder</button>
  </form>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

y en mi component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      usuario: ['', Validators.required],
      contraseña: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }

  guardar(): void {

  }
}
```

Alguien sabe como mostrar en la pantalla cuando un campo lo quieren mandar vacío? o como se manda un mensaje que no es valido lo que están ingresando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes disparar las validaciones desde tu función de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
guardar(): void {
    this.loginForm.markAllAsTouched();
    this.loginForm.updateValueAndValidity();

 if( this.loginForm.valid() ){
    alert('formualario válido')
  }else{
    alert('formualario inválido')
  }
}
```

Después edita tus campos para que muestren un error si hay un error:

```html
<label>Usuario:</label>
<input type="text" formControlName="usuario" [ngClass]="{
                    'is-invalid':f('usuario')?.invalid,
                    'is-valid': f('usuario')?.valid
                  }" class="form-control">
```

Donde `f()` es:

```
f(campo:string){
  return this.loginForm.get("campo")
}
```

Nota que agregue `?` en el html.

### Validaciones con touched.

```
  invalid(campo: AbstractControl | null ): boolean {
    return campo?.touched && campo?.invalid;
  }

  valid(campo: AbstractControl | null): boolean {
    return campo?.touched && campo?.valid;
  }
```

Remplaza en el html:

```
'is-invalid':invalid(f('usuario')),
                    'is-valid': valid(f('usuario'))
```

Para mostrar un texto necesitas saber el tipo de error. Puedes hacer esto.

```
<small *ngIf="f('usuario')?.getError('required')"  > Este campo es necesario </small>
```

Comment: al dar clic en el botón no hace nada, debo de modificar algo al boton?

Comment: Edite la pregunta. Revisala. Tienes que agregar algunas clases para que el error se note. Yo pongo de ejemplo unas de bootstrap, pero puedes remplazarlas por las que quieras. Colorean de rojo o verde , respectivamente ,el input.

Comment: me manda el error en el input en el .valid, dice Object is possibly 'null', el metodo de abajo, va en el component.ts ??

Comment: Si, agrega una validacion. Comprueba que no sea `null` para que quite ese error. Edito la pregunta.

Comment: gracias , ya se ilumina en rojo o en verde, pero si quiero mostrar un mensaje abajo del input?  y por default cuando entro a la pagina esta en rojo  por que no hay nada, pero quiero que eso se marque cuando das clic sin llenar

Comment: Tienes que usar una combinacion con touched. Edito mi pregunta y revisa las nuevas funciones.

Comment: excelente, pero se carga por default, se puede que sea a partir del clic en el boton

Comment: Para eso son las funciones. Revisa mi edición.

Comment: ya las cheque, me mandan Argument of type 'AbstractControl | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: Edita esas funciones para que acepten nulo. Eso deberia dejarte.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes acceder al `FormControl` y usar el método `valid`

`this.loginForm.get('usuario').valid()`, eso retorna `false` si está invalido
`this.loginForm.get('usuario').invalid()`, eso retorna `true` si está invalido

con `this.loginForm.valid()`, validas todo el formulario

puedes usar:

```
guardar(): void {
  if( this.loginForm.valid() ){
    alert('formualario válido')
  }else{
    alert('formualario inválido')
  }
}
```

Puedes desactivar el boton submit añadiendo la directiva:

`<button ... [disabled]="loginForm.invalid()"> ...`

Answer (score 0):

validarlo directamente en el back y retorna el mensaje de error en el front
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto por favor, solo utiliza imágenes cuando sea absolutamente necesario. ;)