# Angular- como es mejor validar un form a nivel de formBuilder o a nivel de modelo bindeado

Tags: angular, formularios, validación, angular7, angular6

estoy remotando angular pues quiero volver con esta herramienta de front, estaba viendo las validaciones.

Y principalmente que tienes 2 opciones por las que puedes guiar tu validacion:

1- **FormBuilder**

Te creas un validator con `require` o lo que necesites, parecido a esto:

```
this.zapatillaForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  nombre:[this.zapatilla.nombre,[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),Validators.maxLength(20)]],
  marca:[this.zapatilla.marca,[Validators.required]],
  precio:[this.zapatilla.precio,[Validators.required,Validators.min(0)]],
  color:[this.zapatilla.color,[Validators.required]],
  stock:[this.zapatilla.stock,[Validators.required]],
});
```

2. **NgModel**

Le asignas una clase js que tengas, y actue como modelo, por ejemplo: `user.js`.

Y siemplemente en el obsubmit, te olvidas del form y validas las propiedades del objeto js. Algo asi:

```
if (user.name.length <0) //no envio el form
```

Debo decir que tener todo en componentes dentro de angular me parece una pasada. Es decir un componente que sea  app-login, otro , app-crear-usuario, y que no tengan que vercon un modelo que a lo mejor mañana tenga un campo nuevo, es decir, prefiero algo compacto en cuanto a componente, pero si que es verdad que bindeando te soluciona muchas cosas. **Pero dependes  de tener un modelo al corriente de cambios del backend**.

Por otra parte la validacion ¿No hay una manera de displayear los errores en bucle en vez de ponerlos debajo de ada correspondiente input?. A esto me refiero:

```
 <div id="nombre_errors"
              class="alert alert-danger"
              *ngIf="nombre.invalid && (nombre.dirty || nombre.touched)">
           <p
             *ngIf="nombre.errors.required"
             class="text-danger"><b>El campo es obligatorio</b>
           </p>
           <p
             *ngIf="nombre.errors.minlength"
             class="text-danger"><b>Caracteres minimos: {{zapatillaForm.get('minLength')}}</b>
           </p>
           <p
             *ngIf="nombre.errors.maxlength"
             class="text-danger"><b>Caracteres maximos: {{zapatillaForm.get('maxLength')}}</b>
           </p>
         </div>
```

Eso debajo de un input y asi con todos. No se podria hacer un `foreach` de validaciones al final???

Comment: Con respecto a las validaciones puedes revisar esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/426851/33391 . Sobre el tema de cual es mejor creo que va en función de la complejidad del código. Los reactiveForms son mas fáciles de mantener que el ngModel en cuanto a que separa la creación del formulario de la vista del mismo. También es posible usar un mismo formulario para mostrar detalles deshabilitándolo y cambiando algunas clases para que se vea como solo lectura.

Comment: @Legna gracias, me ha servido para sacar unas conclusiones que he puesto como respuesta, podrias mirarlo y decirme que te parece y ya de paso si sabrias mi ultima duda ? Muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

### He sacado esta conclusion de las validaciones

```
 <div class="form-group">
         <label
                [class.text-danger]="!first.valid && (first.dirty || first.touched)"
                [class.text-success]="first.valid && (first.dirty || first.touched)"
                [class.font-weight-bold]="(first.dirty || first.touched)">

           First
         </label>
         <input class="form-control"
                [class.border-danger]="!first.valid && (first.dirty || first.touched)"
                [class.border-success]="first.valid && (first.dirty || first.touched)"
                name="first" ngModel  #first="ngModel" required minlength="3" maxlength="10">
         <div *ngIf="!first.valid && (first.dirty || first.touched)">
           <small class="text-danger font-weight-bold" *ngIf="first.errors.required">Campo obligatorio</small>
           <small class="text-danger font-weight-bold" *ngIf="first.errors.minlength">Longitud minima: 3 caracteres</small>
           <small class="text-danger font-weight-bold" *ngIf="first.errors.maxlength">Longitud maxima: 10 caracteres</small>
         </div>
```

Toda esa pesca seria para un campo, que si es validado en verde que si no en rojo (en cuanto a que sea llamativo) depues diferentes smalls que saldrian debajo del input para indicar el error (algo muy importante que a difernrecia de angular no te lo automatiza.. no me gusta eso)

Pero con este ejemplo me quedaria si puediera dinamizar variables del input, me explico, tengo un **maxlength** y un **minlength**. Con valores de **3** y **10** respectivamente.
A la hora de decir que no puede haber mas de x o menos de y. Tengo que ir a donde esta el valor del **min/maxlength** , fijarme en el y ponerlo yo **hardcodeado**. He intentado buscar algo tipo : `first.maxlength.value` para que acceda **automaticamente** al valor que le he puesto pero no he encontrado nada al respecto, y veo que lo hace poco dinamico. Es el unico pero que le veo asi a grosso modo.

#### ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Es posible acceder al error. Intenta poner dentro de los mensajes de validacion {{first.errors | json}}. Si mal no recuerdo debería mostrarte un objeto con los parametros que buscas. Para esto, al crear el formulario, deberías haber definido un `Validators.minlength(3)`. Ahora mismo no puedo comprobar, pero en cuanto pueda te confirmo esto si no es así.